# Eclipse RCP ProjectManager Tree Element cut off

Tags: text, tree, project, viewer

I have an Eclipse RCP 3.x application with a Project Manager Tree Viewer in its own part..
When I expand the root (parent) of the tree, the child's last character is slightly cut off by about 2 pixels.  However when I expand that child's tree, it is no longer cut off but the child of it has its last character cut off, but only slightly by about 2 pixels.

This seems to only be an issue when the tree item ends in a letter 'e'.

Can't understand why this is happening, anyone have any thoughts on how I might be able to remedy this?

Thanks in advance, 
Marv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the only thing I could do to fix the last char from being clipped was to get the existing font size adn increase the font from 9pt to 10pt in the tree view of the Project Manager.  It seemed to help. But to me not as clean as being able to redraw the image with a proper kerning so the curved ending characters won't be cut off by 2 pixels.